# What is the purpose of the constructor?

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, evm, solidity-0.8.x

contract Constructor {

```
string public name;
```

// I thought constructor will prevent the name to change but after deployed the contract, calling the function resulted in changing the name?????

```
constructor(string memory _name) {
    name = _name;
}

function ChangeName(string memory _newName) public {
    name = _newName;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When calling this contract, you must enter a name in the contract call.

For example, if the name of the contract is `Lottery`, then you would call it like so:

```
Lottery("BigAmerica");
```

The constructor does not prevent the change of the name, it simply applies certain data when calling the contract.

Constructor as it's defined in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#constructors):

> A constructor is an optional function declared with the constructor keyword which is executed upon contract creation, and where you can run contract initialisation code.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is what will be called at the deployment of your contract. It allows to run functions or set variables, **only once** during deployment.
It can be useful when you want to pass in arguments instead of hard coding.

[image: constructor]

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#creating-contracts

The constructor doesn't affect the possibility to change the value of a variable after deployment.
Only the variable modifiers such as `public` , `private`, `internal`, `constant`, `immutable` ... will have an effect on state variables initialization and visibility.

If you want a variable that can never be changed then use `constant`;

If you want to be able to initialize a variable at deployment and make it immutable after deployment then use the `immutable` modifier;

[image: constant & immutable]

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#constant-and-immutable-state-variables